# How to pass parameters to destination url using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url-parameters, query-string

I am trying to pass a movie id to the url when a movie is clicked on, and retrieve the movie id in the destination page. I know forms do this by default, but I want to accomplish this with an anchor element.

So for example i have this homepage url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5500/client/index.html
```

I click on a movie on the homepage and the movie has an anchor tag which redirects to a different file:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5500/client/views/movies.html
```

The movie has an id that I want to be available in the `/movies.html` page, and the movies url should look something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5500/client/views/movies.html?movieId=1234
```

How would I accomplish this using javascript?

Here is the html:

```
 <div class="card">
    <a href="${'/client/views/movies.html'}" data-src="1234" >
        <img class="img-size" src="${poster_image}" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="card-body">
       <h6 class="card-title"> ${el.title}</h6>
          <p>${el.release_date}</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You can add the query param in href tag itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the desired parameter in the anchor tag `href` itself like this:

```
 <div class="card">
    <a href="${'/client/views/movies.html?movieId=1234'}" data-src="1234" >
        <img class="img-size" src="${poster_image}" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="card-body">
       <h6 class="card-title"> ${el.title}</h6>
          <p>${el.release_date}</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Wow why didn't i think of that. I thought it was going to be complicated and didn't even realize i could do that. This is what fixed it.  ` <a href="${`/client/views/movies.html?movieId=${el.id}`}`. Thanks